# Usage of commas to separate a sentence beginning with "and in fact..."

Tags: commas, parentheticals

I'm not sure which of these two is the better choice:

"...some properties, which are suggested, and in fact implied, by the conditions 1 and 2."

"...some properties, which are suggested and in fact implied by the conditions 1 and 2."

Is this an example of a parenthetical phrase which has to be separated by two commas?

Comment: They're both fine.  You get to choose a comma-heavy style or a comma-light style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that the best punctuation would be:

> ...some properties which are suggested, and, in fact, implied by the conditions 1 and 2."

The commas may not be absolutely required, but allow for easier comprehension by the reader.
The answer essentially is to write  as one might recite the information.
You could say it this way:

> ...some properties which are suggested, and in fact implied, by the conditions 1 and 2."

if it sounds better and closer to how you want the reader to "hear" it. Without commas, the reader might have to pause to determine what was just read. Adding a comma after "properties" is OK, but really doesn't help, I do not think.